# Excel Countif with wildcards in searched array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wildcard, countif

I've searched for a while, but it looks like all the examples I find are the opposite of what I need. There are many ways to see if a string with wildcards matches any of the values in an array, but I need to go the other way - I need the array to contain wildcards, and check if the string in the target cell matches any of the match strings in the array, but the match strings can contain wild cards.

To put it in context, I am parsing large log files, and there are many lines I wish to ignore (but not delete); so I have a helper column:

```
+---+-------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|   |  A    |    B                                   |  C  (filter for = FALSE)   | Requirement
+---+-------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| 1 | 11:00 | VPN Status                             | =COUNTIF(IgnoreList,B1)>0  + Keep
| 2 | 11:05 | Log at event index 118, time index 115 | =COUNTIF(IgnoreList,B2)>0  + Ignore
| 3 | 11:20 | Log at event index 147, time index 208 | =COUNTIF(IgnoreList,B3)>0  + Ignore
+---+-------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I've tried to put wildcards in my IgnoreList range to catch any of the "Log at event" lines:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| IgnoreList                           +
+--------------------------------------+
| State Runtime 1                      + 
| State Runtime 2                      +
| State Runtime 3                      +
| State Runtime 4                      +
| Log at event index *, time index *   + 
+--------------------------------------+
```

... but this isn't working.

Does anyone know how to check a cell against an array containing wildcards?

My IgnoreList has 60 entries so far, so testing each cell individually isn't really feasible. I could have 30,000 or more entries in the log, so individual testing will be a lot more formulas than I'd hoped to use. I also don't want to edit the formulae when I add an entry to the IgnoreList.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about the `Left()` worksheet function: `Left(...,18) = "Log at event index"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SEARCH, which allows wild card lookups, inside SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(IgnoreList,B1)))>0
```

[image]

---

To use COUNTIF one would need to reverse the criteria and wrap in SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B1,IgnoreList))>0
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks!
I've gone for your second formula as it's smaller, works perfectly.

Comment: @Scott In cell E6, does anything after the first * ? or does the stuff between the * need to be there for it to count?

Comment: @ForwardEd it has to have the `, time ..`  if I remove it from one of the lines it turns to false.  Though it can have anything between the two.